# Cairo x11 doesn't display anything

Tags: c, x11, cairo, xlib

I worked with cairo and X11 before, and had a piece of code working perfectly, and now I am developping a new project (supposed to be a karaoke), and I took a piece of the code that was used to display something on the screen, which worked on the old project, but which doesn't work anymore.
I have been looking for a mistake all day and I must be missing something, because nothing works.
The code is the following.

A first function used to display some text :

```
void display_line(cairo_surface_t *surface, lyrics_line l)
{
   cairo_t *cr;
   cr=cairo_create(surface);
   cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0); // Should paint the window black
   cairo_paint(cr);
   cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1., 1., 1.);
   cairo_select_font_face(cr, "Hacker", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL,CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_BOLD);
   cairo_set_font_size(cr, 13);
   cairo_move_to(cr, 620, 30);
   char text[255];
   strcpy(text, l.text);
   cairo_show_text(cr, text);  // Should print the text in white
   cairo_destroy(cr);
   printf("%s\n", text);
}
```

And the main function, that calls the previous one,

```
void display(song s)
{
   // X11 display
   Display *dpy;
   Window rootwin;
   Window win;
   int scr;
   // init the display
   if(!(dpy=XOpenDisplay(NULL))) {
       fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Could not open display\n");
       exit(1);
   }
   scr=DefaultScreen(dpy);
   rootwin=RootWindow(dpy, scr);
   win=XCreateSimpleWindow(dpy, rootwin, 1, 1, WINSIZEX, WINSIZEY, 0, BlackPixel(dpy, scr), BlackPixel(dpy, scr));
   XStoreName(dpy, win, "Karaoke");
   KeyPressMask|ButtonPressMask|ExposureMask);
   XMapWindow(dpy, win);
   // create cairo surface
   cairo_surface_t *cs;
   cs=cairo_xlib_surface_create(dpy, win, DefaultVisual(dpy, 0), WINSIZEX, WINSIZEY);
   cairo_t *cr;
   cr=cairo_create(cs);
   cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
   cairo_paint(cr);    // Should fill the window in blue
   cairo_destroy(cr);
   int i;
   printf("\n");
   lyrics_line l = {"That's a test", 200};
   display_line(cs, l);
   usleep(s.text[0].length*10000);
   for(i=0; i<s.length; i++)
     {
       display_line(cs, s.text[i]);
       usleep((s.text[i+1].length - s.text[i].length)*10000);
     }
   cairo_surface_destroy(cs); // destroy cairo surface
   XCloseDisplay(dpy); // close the display
 }
```

I don't know if `display_line` causes a problem, because when I simply try to color the window in blue with `display`it doesn't even work.
However, the lyrics **do** display in the console, so the algorithm is not the problem.

What could I be missing ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you try if adding `cairo_surface_flush(cs)` after the drawing helps?

Comment: @UliSchlachter It doesn't change a thing...